# debug second click - toggle dropdown

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

toggle functions only fire on the second click. I had this problem some time ago with a datetimepicker libary. Now the problem exists with bootstrap.

Here is my Jade-Code:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
   li.dropdown
      a(href="#", class="dropdown-toggle", data-toggle="dropdown") Einstellungen 
    b.caret
      ul.dropdown-menu
         li
            a(href="#") test
```

The dropwdown only toggles with the second click. And dont no where i have to search to find the mistake. Is there maybe a code to detect what is happend with my first click?

When is user the css to collapse on hower it works fine, with the first hover :(

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
   display: block;
   margin-top:0px
}
```

The project is to big to post it on Fiddle :(

I hope you can give me some advices.

Thanks!

Comment: I got this problem after I included angular-ui-bootstrap into the application. Solved it using markthethomas' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be using the angular-ui-bootstrap route instead of trying to get vanilla bootstrap javascript to work with your angular app. Below is a link to the angular-ui-bootstrap site; try implementing one of the angular-native directives for a drop down and see if that does the trick.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Aside from that, it's hard to help if we can't recreate your problem. Can you try recreating  small version of the problem in a codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: I will try it. thank you very much! the problem is, that when i recreate it it work :D So I think its mybe a problem with some dependencies :( Could it be a solution to catch the click event?

Comment: glad it works now; the angular-ui libraries are all written with much more native control, so even though you can 'catch' the event without them, they would probably give you much more control. Let me know if you have any questions about implementing it

Comment: you are my hero...i have already used ui.bootstrap...but didn't delete the bootsrap.js. I have never think about that! So thank you very much! I dont need jQuery, too?

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted out. As of the current version, Bootstrap depends on jquery 1.9 as it's minimum dependency. Here's a link to the `bower.json` file for the bootstrap repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/v3.1.1/bower.json